# (Android) How to set default gps position in mapview

Tags: android, controller, geolocation, gps, android-mapview

So i have an app that has to show the location of a number of shops, depending on which one you choose.
The XML layout for the page with the mapView is part of a ViewFlipper, and the part that has the map layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back2"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backLocation3"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_zuruck2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/backLocation3"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/businesslounge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapPlaceHolderLayout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/backLocation3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewMap"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>







    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mapLocation"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mapPlaceHolderLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewMap"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:text="@string/maplocation"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/purple" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/phonereserve"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rezervephone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The part of the code that relates to the mapview is:

```
public class StandorteFragment extends MapHostFragment {

public String text2;
private RelativeLayout mapPlaceHolderLayout;
public AQuery aQuery;

private MapView myMapView;
private GeoPoint geoPoint;
private MapController mc;

@Override
protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivityClass() {
    return LocationMapActivity.class;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location, container, false);
    ViewFlipperStandorte = (ViewFlipper) v.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipperLocation);
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint( (int) (48.949997* 1E6), (int) (22.140213 * 1E6));
    mapPlaceHolderLayout = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.mapPlaceHolderLayout);
    mapPlaceHolderLayout.addView(onCreateMapView());
//      myMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapPlaceHolderLayout);
//        mc = myMapView.getController();
//        mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
//
```

It works but doesn't show nothing in the mapView. If i don't comment those 3 lines with myMapView and animate geoPoint, it force closes.
What do I have to do?

EDIT: onCreateMapView:

```
public View onCreateMapView() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), getActivityClass());
    final Window w = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(ACTIVITY_TAG,
            intent);
    final View wd = w != null ? w.getDecorView() : null;

    if (wd != null) {
        ViewParent parent = wd.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) parent;
            v.removeView(wd);
        }

        wd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        wd.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        if (wd instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ((ViewGroup) wd)
                    .setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        }
    }
    return wd;
}
```

Comment: Have you set up the Google Map API Key?

Comment: yup, the map now works but don't know how to set centerposition

Comment: there's some good Maps tutorials here:
http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/using-google-maps-in-android-development-tutorial-part-1/

Among other things, they cover setting the center point

Comment: i managed to make it run, and set the gps position, so thanks, it helped a little, but know i get an "Couldn't get connection factory client" error on my program, and i don't know why, because it worked just fine, until i accidentaly deleted my debugkey. I made another API key, and tried the Debug Version and also the Production Signing version, and still no luck to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapPlaceHolderLayout.addView(onCreateMapView()); called MapHostFragment which called LocalActivityManagerFragment which somehow goes to LocationMapActivity which extends MapActivity, so here i could instantiate the Mapcontroller and everything went as normal form there

Answer (score 1):

Well the R.id.mapPLaceHolderLayout in your xml is not a mapview so you can't cast it to one.  That line will cause an exception.

Comment: ok, but how do i use the mapview? because i know mapPlaceHolderLayout is a layout, that loads up the map.

Comment: what does the code onCreateMapView do?  Post that code please.

Comment: Ok, apparently I am missing this, but I don't see where you are actually adding a MapView to the layout.  It is not in the XML and I don't see it in the code anywhere.  You need to inflate a MapView and add it into the Layout.

Comment: and could you please explain me a little how to do that? kind of a noob at android, i learned a lot these last weeks, but still have a lot to cover. All i see in the frame, are those squares, that you see when the map is not loaded in googlemaps.

Comment: I made it show the map, but still have no ideea how to set the default geoposition where the map starts

Comment: Read the documentation specifically as related to the getController method: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView

Comment: i know how to use the mapView, and connect it to the mapcontroller, but the problem, because i have a tab activity, with fragments and the mapView in a fragment.So i can't really instantiate the <com.google.android.maps.MapView/> in the Relative Layout because it crashes. so I have to let it empty, and the onCreateMapView() fills the layout with the map. But how can i get to the mapView, so that i can put the controller on it? I even tried:  MapView myMapView = (MapView) mapPlaceHolderLayout.getChildAt(0); but i still get Force Close....

Comment: Ok, the parent activity of this fragment needs to be a MapActivity, is that how yours is set up?

Comment: public abstract class MapHostFragment extends LocalActivityManagerFragment {
inside the onCreateMapView() - you see in the question
}
And if I go through it its: public class LocalActivityManagerFragment extends Fragment {

}